# How to get the checked data using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

my Objective is to remove the list of selected objects, if i *checkAll* then it should show empty list or if i select one item from the Table then it should remove the selected item from the list. But i couldn't able to get the checked object.

Json look like :

```
const data =[
{
id: "12shgdfyd78"
name: "ABC"
isSelected: true
phone: "1234569874"
},
{
id: "18htfdwcfe78"
name: "EFG"
isSelected: true
phone: "9587463215"
}
]
```

if i select the first one then the whole object need to appear, But could not able to get it.

If have tried in this way:

```
handleCheck = (e) => {
let value = e.target.name //will get the phone number
let checked = e.target.checked;
let checkedList = this.props.data.map((item)=> item.phone == value? Object.assign(item,{isSelected: checked,}): item
this.setState({checkItems: checkedList})
}
```

```
handleSubmit = () => {
const data = this.state.checkItems.filter(item=>item.isSelected).map(item=>item.phone)
}
```

But didn't get the object.

Can anyone please help me in this query?

Comment: I think there is a better way of doing this , check my answer

Comment: @سعيد   -  Hi, i want to write handleCheck for the checkbox, COuld you please help in handling the checkbox and getting the object?

Comment: I have provided an answer

Comment: @سعيد - But that is a functional component

Comment: it works the same for class , okkay I'll convert it to class

Comment: check my edit  have converted it to class component

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would go about it

```
class CheckBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  }

  render() {
    <input type="checkbox" onClick={e=>this.props.handleCheck(this.props.object)}   name={this.props.object.name} value={object}>
}
}

 
class CheckBoxGroup extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
   
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state={
          data:[
         {
            id: "12shgdfyd78"
            name: "ABC"
            isSelected: true
            phone: "1234569874"
         },
         {
            id: "18htfdwcfe78"
            name: "EFG"
            isSelected: true
             phone: "9587463215"
         }
        ],
        selectedObject:null,
       } 
  }


   handleCheck = (object) => {
   console.log(object)
   }

   render(){
 return this.data.map((d,i)=><CheckBox key={i} handleCheck={this.handleCheck }  index={i} object={d} />)
}

  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use `array.map` and `array.filter` function to achieve your use case,
please checkout the codesandbox example i made [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/building-a-checkbox-component-with-react-and-styled-components-forked-1c7x7).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you have Select All checkbox and other checkboxes based on data in your state. If one of them is unchecked then it should not display and select all is selected then it should bring back all. It can be achieved using `filter` and `map` functions of array. Check below example in below link it is somewhat near that you are looking for:

[Select All Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-gagarin-e5rsz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)